# Running during COVID Pandemic Situation?

Tags: running, health, calisthenics, health-risk, covid-19

I used to run and I enjoyed it a lot. I also practice calisthenics: push ups, pull ups, dips, etc.

During this pandemic situation I have kind of stopped running, and diminished my workouts a lot (I used to workout at the park), but my main question here is: *should we run with a mask?*

If so, could that cause other problems related to fungal infections or other stuff? Such as getting wet in the face because of breathing / sweating into the mask.

Can we still run safely in this pandemic situation without a mask? Should we get concerned that while we are running outside we could maybe breath in droplets from other people that could contain the Coronavirus?

What is the chance of getting infected while running, for example, in a relatively small park, repeating the same "circuit/path" as other runners or people walking by? (or any other "circuit/path" that is also taken by other people)

What **evidence** do we actually have on this matter?

Comment: Running is one of the Mayo Clinic's approved activities because it is by nature a very socially distant activity and the outdoors has excellent ventilation which greatly reduces risk of infection. https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/coronavirus/in-depth/safe-activities-during-covid19/art-20489385

Comment: I've read that you should increase your following distance if you're behind someone running but other than that, I haven't gotten sick from walking/running in the park without a mask. However, I definitely don't feel qualified to answer this.

Comment: @DeeV well, it is outdoors, but if you think like, you are breathing air someone might have just breath out on your way ( your running path.. ) , they say the particles can stay in the air for hours.. so this is why I ask also

Comment: unfotrunately, this is off topic as you're basically asking everyone's opinion, which isn't how the SE model works. I really encourage you to find a way to not make it a discussion solicitation, because I think this is a good question to have on the site.

Comment: Jogging past someone is a very low risk activity. It takes time to transmit Covid-19. Google "viral load".

Comment: @ChaimG ok but if you think about it you are running for some time, and might get exposed for some time depending on the running roadmap...

Comment: @JohnP ok I understand I will try gather data that made me do this question and influenced my mind as soon as I can

Comment: @PabloCamara It usually takes at least 15 almost consecutive minutes of *indoor* exposure to build up enough viral load for it to start incubating. Outdoor exposure is much weaker. Important: Every minute of breathing fresh air reduces viral load. So, if you pass by another jogger for a few seconds and then you continue on jogging by yourself, your viral load will dissipate.

Answer (score 0):

To ensures the preventive measures during the exercise our park management has allowed us to run just one sided. And we people try much to keep ourselves distant by running in open place. Using mask can definitely effect your respiratory system and you can feel difficulty in breathing during breathing. So I'd suggest you to try staying distant from other people as much as you can and use the mask when your body is in normal state.